# Distribution for the extreme values of a cumulative sum of normal variables

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a sample $X$ of $n$ iid Normal random variables $(X_1,X_2,..,X_n)$.

Now, define the sample mean $u=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and let $Y_i=X_i-u$.

Let $Z_k=\sum_{i=1}^k {Y_i}$. Note that $Z_0=0$ and $Z_n=0$

I want to know what the distribution of $\max_{1\le k \le n}(Z_k)$ is.
The distribution of $\min_{1\le k \le n}(Z_k)$ should be symmetric.

What is this distribution's CDF as a function of n?

Apologies if this question is trivial.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why this question was voted to close. To the OP: You should look into "Brownian bridge".

Comment: The difficulty of this question depends on the level of precision you are aiming for. The variance of $u$ is small, so up to a small error the distribution of $\max Z_i$ is the same as he distribution of $\max X_i$. The correlation between $\max X_i$ and $u$ is non-zero, but very small, so a better approximation would be the convolution of $u$, which is normal, and $\max X_i$. The exact distribution might be really difficult.